# Dynamically create class Names in react

Tags: reactjs

I am currently mapping over some data and I would like to create a unique className for each result being returned specifically for the test.typical_dq_domain.

For example below shows what data is being returned... With the value displaying Uniqueness would like to have a className called Uniqueness etc.

[image]

```
 {unitTestTemplates.map(test =>
          <div className='Table CreateUnitTestsGrid' style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
            <div>{test.test_type}</div>
            <div>{test.typical_dq_domain}</div>
          </div>
        )}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template strings to create dynamic classes based on values in any variables you're using! In this case, if the `typical_dq_domain` property contains the string that you want to be your class name, you can do something like this.

```
{unitTestTemplates.map((test, index) =>
   <div className={`Table CreateUnitTestsGrid ${test.typical_dq_domain}`}>
      <div>{test.test_type}</div>
      <div>{test.typical_dq_domain}</div>
   </div>
)}
```

Then, if `test.typical_dq_domain` had a value of "VALIDITY", for example, that div would have classes "Table", "CreateUnitTestsGrid", and "VALIDITY" applied to it.

Comment: thanks, just getting an unexpected token with the } on the end. Any idea!?

Comment: Sorry, which } are you referring to? The one at the end of the whole code snippet, or the one at the end of  the className definition?

Comment: Ah that's my bad, I had an extra paren in there at the top :) I fixed it, it should be fine now.

Comment: Thank you, amazing! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look I hope it's helpful.
Thanks

```
{unitTestTemplates.map((test,index) =>
          <div className={`Uniqueness_${index}`} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
            <div>{test.test_type}</div>
            <div>{test.typical_dq_domain}</div>
          </div>
        )}
        </div>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, what if I wanted the rest of the typical_dq_domain values to have a unique class. Like for instances consistency would then have a class Name of consistency

Comment: Welcome, Please have a look `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector` I hope You will get your answer.

Comment: You need to use `querySelector ` to select a particular row on behalf of a class

Comment: @tjhunt Please mark as an accepted answer for other's developers easily identify the right one.